# How to get content width of uiwebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, gif

I load Gif image like this

```
[webView2 loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Apple_jumps" ofType:@"gif"]] MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

and I want to set to center position of uiwebview, but I can't to get width of content. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.height` or `document.width` from javascript

```
// in init
_WebView.delegate = YourClass; // probably self

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
{
  int w = [[_WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
  _WebView.userInteractionEnabled = w > 200;
}
```

more info here: https://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/objective-c-get-uiwebview-html-page-size/

Comment: document.width returns always width of iphone screen (320), document.height works fine.

Comment: No, document.width return the width of your page. If your page use meta tags for iphone, size is 320px.